# I'm trying to query MySQL as a promise, but I keep getting "unhandledpromiserejection error"

Tags: google-app-engine, unhandled-exception

Please help I'm trying to deploy my app to App Engine/CloudSQL but I keep getting :

> "UnhandledPromiserejectWarning": Cannot enqueue after fatal error..

I'm trying to query MySQL as promise, when I don't I handle the exception it works fine locally, but when I deploy it doesn't work.
How can I handle promise rejection, please Help Thanks

This is db.js

```
  const db = require('./Mysql')

 const query = (q, data) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 db.query(q, data, (err, res) => (err ? reject(err) : resolve(res)))
  })
    .then(res => console.log(res)) 
   .catch(err => console.error(err))
```

This is Mysql.js

```
  { SQL_SOCKET, SQL_USER, SQL_PASSWORD, SQL_DATABASE } = process.env

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  socketPath: SQL_SOCKET,
  user: SQL_USER,
  password: SQL_PASSWORD,
  database: SQL_DATABASE,
  charset: 'utf8mb4',
})

module.exports = db
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this problem a few years ago when I tried using the [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) module within an `expressJS` application and attempted to use `async/await`. The error could also come from querying on a connection in which a fatal error occured, see [here](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql/issues/832). As such, best practices dictates that on queries, you open a connection, start a query transaction, commit the query and then release the connection afterwards -- allowing you to rollback whenever an error occurs. I do not see this process happening here so it could be a possibility.

In any case, I can provide you with an alternative, which is the method I ended up going with. Basically, I digressed promisifying `query()` myself and instead let [node handle it](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original).

**An example of using query without transaction:**

> /backend/database/database.js

```js
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('../config/config').mysql;
const util = require('util');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: require('../config/config').cLimit,
    host: db.host,
    user: db.user,
    password: db.password,
    database: db.database
});

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query);

async function query(cmd) {
    try {
        let result = await pool.query(cmd);
        return result;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

module.exports = {
    query
};
```

Which can then be used in your models like such:

> /backend/models/User.js

```js
const db = require('../database/database');
async function getUserById(userId) {
    const cmd = `SELECT * FROM Users WHERE userId = ${userId}`;

    try {
        let result = await db.query(cmd);
        return result;
    } catch(error) {
        throw {
            message: error
        }
    }
}

module.exports = {
    getUserById
};
```

Which in turn, can be called from your route handler like such:

> /backend/routes/users.js

```js
const router = require('express').Router();
const User = require('../models/User');


router.get('/getUserById/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        let user = await User.getUserById(req.params.userId);
        res.status(200).send({ user });
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(400).send({ error: 'Unable to fetch user' });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```